# Debian Php Max file upload

Tags: php, linux, apache, debian, raspberry-pi

First off I'm new to Linux.
I've installed Apache, Mysql and PHP on to a raspberry pi(Debian, not raspbian, so all command driven), and i've written a file upload php script, which works for small files, but I can't get it to upload a 85M file, it doesn't come back with any warnings or errors(I have taken the script size limitations out).
I have tried changing the max_upload, etc in the /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and nothing makes a difference, am I missing something or is there a limitation on the pi?
The point of this website is to allow large uploads directly onto the company network as have shared the upload directory.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably did everything right, but didn't do enough. To my knowledge, there are a few things to change in a config:

```
# Max file size:
upload_max_filesize = some value


# But let's not forget that files are a part of POST request, so let's set its limits as well:
post_max_size = some value
```

Maybe this will help

Comment: Thank you for your help, I thought I had already done this, but I also needed to do it in the /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini, as well as in the /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
  php_value post_max_size 200M
```

or this

```
<?php ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '200M'); ?>
```